# Why are there so few sources available from post-Tanach, pre-Mishnah?

Tags: anshei-knesset-hagedolah

Why are there so few sources available from the Anshei Knesses HaGedolah?

We have some Sifrei Tanach from them, written with Nevuah (Trei Asar) or Ruach HaKodesh (Ezra, Esther, Chronicles). We have some oral traditions which were later written down as a part of the Mishnah (Avos 1:1-2, for example) or left as Braisos later recorded in the Gemara (Megillah 17b, for example).

Why was more not recorded from their period? Why didn’t the same rationale for recording the Mishnah not apply to them, that they could have written down more of their enactments? For instance, I can’t find a source earlier than *post-Talmudic* with the exact text of Shemoneh Esrei.

Comment: דברים שבעל פה אי אתה רשאי לכותבן

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.115b.2?with=Rashi&lang=he

Comment: @Josh עת לעשות לה׳ הפרו תורתך has been the excuse since the Mishnah. Why should this be any different? And as for your link from Shabbos – all the more so!

Comment: I think the Mishnaic period is when עת לעשות started being employed, not before

Comment: The exact text of shmone esrei may not have been written by them

Comment: @robev Clearly, but why?

Comment: Why would you think it should have applied? Was there a problem then with forgetting things?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Jewish-Literature-Between-Bible-Mishnah/dp/0800699157